# How to get exception between two tables using SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables like this:

```
Table_Registration
Table_login
```

I am inserting same data into both the tables at same time, but I want if data inserted into one table and other will not insert means then I need an exception.

This is my stored procedure.

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_UserInformation] 
    (@FullName varchar(300),
     @FatherName varchar(300),
     @DOB varchar(50),
     @PlaceofBirth varchar(200),
     @EmailId varchar(300),
     @Address varchar(300),
     @State varchar(150),
     @Password varchar(50),
     @Role varchar(50),
     @Status varchar(200) output)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @COUNT1 INT, @COUNT2 int

    SELECT @COUNT1 = COUNT(*) 
    FROM Table_Registraiton 
    WHERE EmailId = @EmailId 

    SELECT @COUNT2 = COUNT(*) 
    FROM Table_login 
    WHERE EmailId = @EmailId 

    IF(@COUNT1 > 0 or @COUNT2 > 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @Status = 'Duplicate'
    END
    ELSE if(@COUNT1 = 0 AND @COUNT2 = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Table_Registration(FullName, FatherName, DOB, PlaceofBirth,
                                       EmailId, Address, State)
        VALUES (@FullName, @FatherName, @DOB, @PlaceofBirth,
                @EmailId, @Address, @State)

        INSERT INTO Table_login (Name, EmailId, Password, Role)
        VALUES (@FullName, @EmailId, @Password, @Role)

        SET @Status = 'Success'
    END
END
```

My question is that if data is inserted into `Table_Registration` and not inserted into `Table_login` then I need an exception from status as output parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Need to use output parameter to get status for client,You can use RaiseError

First Wrap your inserts in one transaction..

```
Begin Tran
INSERT INTO Table_Registration(FullName, FatherName, DOB, PlaceofBirth,
                                       EmailId, Address, State)
        VALUES (@FullName, @FatherName, @DOB, @PlaceofBirth,
                @EmailId, @Address, @State)

        INSERT INTO Table_login (Name, EmailId, Password, Role)
        VALUES (@FullName, @EmailId, @Password, @Role)
Set @status='Success'
Commit tran
```

Then in Catch block,use RaiseError

```
Begin Catch
RAISERROR('Insert Failed',16,1)
End Catch
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a transaction to ensure that if data is not inserted into one table, then the whole operation fails. That way you will not have inconsistent data.

You can implement it something like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION AddUserLogin
INSERT INTO Table_Registration(FullName, FatherName, DOB, PlaceofBirth, EmailId, Address, State)
    VALUES (@FullName, @FatherName, @DOB, @PlaceofBirth, @EmailId, @Address, @State)
IF @@Error <> 0
BEGIN
    SET @Status = 'ERROR: There was a problem when creating the registration record.'
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION AddUserLogin
    RETURN -1
END
INSERT INTO Table_login (Name, EmailId, Password, Role)
    VALUES (@FullName, @EmailId, @Password, @Role)
IF @@Error <> 0
BEGIN
    SET @Status = 'ERROR: There was a problem when creating the login record.'
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION AddUserLogin
    RETURN -1
END
-- this part will only run if there are no errors above. All the inserts above are only permanently committed to the database at this point.
COMMIT TRANSACTION AddUserLogin
SET @Status = 'Success'
```

Answer (score 1):

i think,if you don't want to insert due to any reason then raising exception for this is bad idea.you can simple rollback and don't insert and return suitable output which indicate what happen in proc.

try something like this,(correct it if any suntax error)

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_UserInformation] 
    (@FullName varchar(300),
     @FatherName varchar(300),
     @DOB varchar(50),
     @PlaceofBirth varchar(200),
     @EmailId varchar(300),
     @Address varchar(300),
     @State varchar(150),
     @Password varchar(50),
     @Role varchar(50),
     @Status INT output
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY


    DECLARE EmailId1 VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE EmailId2 VARCHAR(50)

    SELECT EmailId1 = EmailId
    FROM Table_Registraiton 
    WHERE EmailId = @EmailId 

    SELECT EmailId2 = EmailId
    FROM Table_login 
    WHERE EmailId = @EmailId 

        set @Status=0

    IF(EmailId1 IS NOT NULL AND EmailId2 IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @Status =1 -- 'Duplicate'
    END
     else
        begin   
        begin transaction
     if(EmailId1 IS  NULL)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Table_Registration(FullName, FatherName, DOB, PlaceofBirth,
                                       EmailId, Address, State)
        VALUES (@FullName, @FatherName, @DOB, @PlaceofBirth,
                @EmailId, @Address, @State)



        SET @Status =2 -- REGISTRATION 'Success'
    END
    if(EmailId2 IS  NULL and @Status=2)
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO Table_login (Name, EmailId, Password, Role)
        VALUES (@FullName, @EmailId, @Password, @Role)

        SET @Status =@Status+3-- 'Success'
    END
        commit
end
    END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
        if(@@TRANCOUNT>0)
            rollback
            RAISERROR('Insert Failed',16,1)

        END CATCH
END
```